# Setting Visual C++ Executable Directories (PATH env variable) for a project in CMake

Tags: visual-c++, build, path, cmake

On the project property pages there is a VC++ Directories tab, on that tab there is an "Executable Directories" option which is basically there to set the PATH variable when building the project.

I need to add the path to a Python interpreter there, which I know about and can infer beforehand by means of the ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} variable.

Is there currently way to set it in CMakeLists.txt?

Thanks.

Comment: CMake does not have support for that however I believe you can set this is set in .user files (these are xml) in the CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.

Comment: I was afraid that was the case, an alternative tool path would be a good feature to add to CMake IMO.
I'll look into .user files, and the best way to achieve what I need.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now 4 years later with [*CMake 3.12*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/release/3.12.html#variables) you can finally do this by overriding variables:

`CMAKE_VS_SDK_EXECUTABLE_DIRECTORIES`

As a matter of fact, you can modify all of those entries you see in the *VC++ Directories* tab: `CMAKE_VS_SDK_EXCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` `CMAKE_VS_SDK_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` `CMAKE_VS_SDK_LIBRARY_DIRECTORIES` `CMAKE_VS_SDK_LIBRARY_WINRT_DIRECTORIES` `CMAKE_VS_SDK_REFERENCE_DIRECTORIES` `CMAKE_VS_SDK_SOURCE_DIRECTORIES`

However, be careful: this a write-only variable. The best thing you can do right now not to lose the directories that are there by default is this:
`set( CMAKE_VS_SDK_EXECUTABLE_DIRECTORIES $(VC_ExecutablePath_x64);$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath);$(VS_ExecutablePath);$(MSBuild_ExecutablePath);$(FxCopDir);$(PATH);WhateverElseYouNeed )`